# Is it okay to store cold beer at room temps after conditioning?

Tags: beer, temperature, storage

I brewed a nice batch of Black Cherry Ale, which has been bottle conditioning at 35F for about 5 weeks.  I will need space in the fridge for a keg of Summer Ale in about two weeks.

My basement temps stay around 60-64F and I'm wondering if storing the bottles at 60F+ will adversely affect the character of the beer.

Is it okay to let it warm up a bit in storage once it's done?

Comment: Does bottle conditioning just mean aging here or carbonating?  Because if its really an Ale then I don't think you are getting much carbonation or conditioning (aging) at 35F.

Comment: Aging.  It carbonated in the bottles for three weeks and then went into the fridge.  Cold aging has helped a lot.  It clarified the ale remarkably and the fruit flavor has mellowed.  It tastes and looks great with a striking rose-colored head.

Answer (score 3):

You probably won't be able to notice any difference in a finished lager stored at 65°F versus 35°F.  Keep in mind that it will age faster at warmer temperatures, though.

Comment: 65F is still an OK storage temp though.

Answer (score 1):

I have stored 5% ABV beers at 22C/72F (in the dark) and they have been good after a year.